# How to configure my enviorment in such a way that a proper (different from the system one) version of library is used

Tags: rhel, gcc, libraries, scientific-linux, c++

I guess that this question is a borderline between ServerFault and StackOverflow and this site. But I think that U&L is most relevant.

I have some `C++` code that depends on a library in version `X` and system provides version `Y` (X>Y). I have compiled this library and placed resulting files into `/opt/lib_name/X/lib`, version `Y` is installed in `/usr/lib64`. I want to link against `so` libraries.

Now I'd like to create some script that somehow enables version `X`, so any code I build with `gcc` is compiled against version `X` without any changes in the makefiles.

For now I set `LIBRARY_NAME_DIR` variable and in the makefile i just append `-L $LIBRARY_NAME_DIR`, which works but requires me to change makefiles.

Is there any way to do to do this sort of things without having root access to the computer.

Note: while I believe that answer to this question does not depend on the specific libary or the code, all details for my particular problem are here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24189130/7918.

What I have tried:

- I have set: `LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do this robustly purely with environmental variables. The problem with using `LIBRARY_PATH` seems to be that any given `-L` option has precedence. If for any reason the `gcc` command has `-L/usr/lib64`, this will be searched first an the older version of the library will be found. Seemingly you are going to change the Makefiles, you should also be careful that a `-L/usr/lib64` does not appear first.

Looking at your SO question though, it doesn't look like the above is an issue. However, there is an unnecessary trailing `:` on the value of your `LIBRARY_PATH` variable, which might explain why it didn't work.

Also, as noted in the answer to the SO question, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used by the dynamic linker and is only relevant at *runtime* for your application. This can be used if the location of the dynamic libraries cannot be found when the application is run. What is used by the GNU linker is `LD_RUN_PATH`, which essentially does for `-rpath` what `LIBRARY_PATH` does for `-rpath`, except that specifying any `-rpath` means that `LIBRARY_PATH` will be ignored (and not just given lower precedence).

What you could try then is:

```
LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib_name/X/lib LD_RUN_PATH=/opt/lib_name/X/lib make
```

---

Something that might be more robust is to create a wrapper script for `gcc` that includes the necessary options, eg:

```
#!/bin/sh
gcc -L/opt/lib_name/X/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/lib_name/X/lib "$@"
```

Name the file `gcc`, make it executable and put it in a directory by itself (or at least one where there are no files with the same name as vital commands). Then you could run `make` like:

```
PATH=/path/to/script:$PATH make
```

Comment: Thanks! After additional debugging it turns out that the makefile (provided with the model I use) added ``-L/usr/lib64``. Or it was added by this:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7493620/7918. So there really is no robust way.